# Java string/stringbuilder inserts null in MySql database

Tags: java, mysql, string, stringbuilder

Java String always sends null to MySQL database.

I have a program that works fine on command prompt and gives desired output but when I save value to database it always save null.

```
void hddName(String ip) {
 
  try {
         String commands="cmd /c wmic.exe DISKDRIVE  get name";//HDD Details
         //System.out.println({"CMD", "/C", "WMIC OS GET Installdate,SerialNumber"});
         Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
         process.getOutputStream().close(); //Closing output stream of the process
         System.out.println();
         StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        //Reading sucessful output of the command
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(s).toString();//append output 
    }
        System.out.println("result"+sb);//gives result with null keyword
        String ss=sb.toString();//gives result with null keyword
        System.out.println("result"+ss);
        try{
                System.out.println(s);
                Connection conn;
                Statement stmt;
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/system","root","");
                stmt= conn.createStatement();
                String sql="update sys set hdname='"+ss+"' where ip='"+ip+"'";// save null to mysql database
                int val= stmt.executeUpdate(sql);  
                conn.close();
                stmt.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                
            }
    // Reading error if any
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
    while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
     System.out.println(s);//any error
    }
   } 
  catch (IOException e)
 {
   e.printStackTrace(); //TODO: necessary exception handling
  }
  // return s;
 }
```

Comment: btw, something off topic: you should NOT call `toString()` at `sb.append(s).toString();//append output `

Answer (score 0):

Is it printing null in your sysouts? is sb allways null?

```
    System.out.println("result"+sb);//gives result with null keyword
    String ss=sb.toString();//gives result with null keyword
    System.out.println("result"+ss);
```

Try

```
String ss= "";
    //Reading sucessful output of the command
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getOutputStream()));
while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    ss = ss + s.toString();//append output 
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is printing like                                                                                                                                                                                   Name       \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0                                                                                                               null                                                                                                            but when I insert it to mysql database it's only insert NULL

Comment: It is printing like                                                                                                                                                                                   ---------{ Name       \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0                                                                                                               null }     ------------------                                                                                                       but when I insert it to mysql database it's only insert NULL

Comment: Im not sure what you need to save, but... have you tried: "process.getOutputStream()" instead of "process.getInputStream()"?

Comment: I just want to save       Name \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0

Comment: I just want to save                                                                                    Name \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0                                                                          Everything working fine except it saves result null in data base means null after result over write the string value before inserting in data base. I just want to remove null or stop it to over write before inserting into database

Answer (score 0):

Never embed value as part of the SQL.  You are making your program vulnerable to SQL-injection.

Do something like:

```
stmt= conn.prepareStatement("update sys set hdname= ? where ip=?");
stmt.setString(1, ss);
stmt.setString(2, ip);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

If you are sure that `ss` is not `null`, then probably the problem is caused by weird SQL constructed by your method.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of BufferedReader. Since I was reading from buffer. and finally it puts null in variable. So, I first write my output to file and then read from it and then saved to database.